# Jmeter - Usage of item based on the condition

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have defined multiple countries at user defined variables as list:

[image]

Then in another sample i use specific country as ex: PL

What is the easiest way, based of the usage of specific country, to enter in the loop?

I know with ${__groovy(vars.get("countries") == "AR")} is possible to compare with 1 country, but how can i compare extracted country with all the countries in the list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate all the countries it's better to go for the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), in this case you need to transform the `countries` variable into the following pattern:

- `country_1=PL`
- `country_2=PT`
- `country_3=RO`
- etc.

If you're looking for a [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code to do the conversion:

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) at the place where you need to "enter the loop"
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.get('countries').trim().split(' ').eachWithIndex { country, index ->
       vars.put('country_' + ++index, country.trim())
   }
   ```
3. Add ForEach Controller after the JSR223 Sampler and configure it like:

   [image]
4. That's it, you should be able to iterate all the countries, defined in the `countries` variable

   [image]

Comment: As i understood: i should amend as:      countries: country_1=PL country_2=PT country_3=RO country_4=AR   but why when matches, is not entering into the loop? what i am doing wrong?